# Formula for MLM Calculator

Tags: regression, calculator

I'm a coder, but not necessarily an expert mathematician, so I think this is the best place to ask this...  I was recently hired to create an MLM calculator.  Here is an example: http://leadersclub.com/calculator/ (you have to scroll down to see it).  After accepting the project, the client said he doesn't have the formula.  First I tried all kinds of PHP loops withg multiple multiplication, addition, subtractions, and even sine/cosines with no luck.  So I tried using some regression calculators like the ones at http://xuru.org/rt/TOC.asp, but there's always a huge margin of error on the formulas I get.  Is there something that might be better for that in figuring out how this example calculator works?

Comment: Were you basing your calculations on data provided by the client?

Comment: "This calculator is based on observing over 1000 organizations, successful and unsuccessful, over a 15-year time frame. The organizations represented multiple network marketing companies." This means it's **not using only the data you put in** but also an extensive dataset that's probably very valuable and you don't get access to it except through this calculator. If you get anything close to that using the deterministic formulas, go for it, forget the margin or just compensate for it as you see fit. **The result is not going to be promised income in any sense anyway.**

Comment: It looks like this is not a job for a coder.  Either get comparable data (and have a statistician analyze it) or license the existing program from leadersclub.com.

Comment: Nothing was provided by the client...unfortunately.  Appreciate you reading the page with the calculator and finding that info (@The Vee)... I guess I should have read that also, but I thought it was just a bunch of sales copy.  Ummm.... I can't see anyone else besides a coder creating the PHP loops to display the form, but maybe they should have had a statistician get the formulas needed for the code to implement (@Robert).  Thanks for the help there, guys.  I'll just deal with the error margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like The Vee said... it's not possible.  The database of actual real results is needed in order to calculate the table.